# R recoding days since start to study week

Tags: r

Suppose I have the following `tibble`:

```
tb <- tibble(subject = rep(c("a", "b", "c"), each = 20), days = rep(-2:17, 3))

# A tibble: 60 x 2
   subject  days
   <chr>   <int>
 1 a          -2
 2 a          -1
 3 a           0
 4 a           1
 5 a           2
 6 a           3
 7 a           4
 8 a           5
 9 a           6
10 a           7
```

Now, I want create a variable that recodes the day variable to a variable holding the study week.

However, I want to avoid, ofc, doing this "manually" in a large `case_when()` statement as more data comes in every now and then. Starting from day 0, I want this variables value to rise by 1 every 7 days. Everything below 0 gets a - 1 (here its not important to count weeks).

Exemplary output:

```
# A tibble: 60 x 2
   subject  days  study_week
   <chr>   <int>       <int>
 1 a          -2         -1
 2 a          -1         -1
 3 a           0          1
 4 a           1          1
 5 a           2          1
 6 a           3          1
 7 a           4          1
 8 a           5          1
 9 a           6          1
10 a           7          2
```

Comment: Are you counting week from `0` to `6` or `1` to `7`?

Comment: 0 to 6 but I guess a solution would be similar when counting from 1 to 7.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
tb %>%
  mutate(study_week = ifelse(days < 0, -1, floor(days / 7) + 1))


#   <chr>   <int>      <dbl>
# 1 a          -2         -1
# 2 a          -1         -1
# 3 a           0          1
# 4 a           1          1
# 5 a           2          1
# 6 a           3          1
# 7 a           4          1
# 8 a           5          1
# 9 a           6          1
#10 a           7          2
```

Comment: yea now I feel embarassed as its that simple.